# Django-admin order by multiple fields

Tags: django, django-admin

How do I order by multiple fields in the django-admin?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

Set ordering in your model `Meta`:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ["some_field", "other_field"]
```

and add this class in `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList

class SpecialOrderingChangeList(ChangeList): 
    """ 
     Django 1.3 ordering problem workaround 
     from 1.4 it's enough to use `ordering` variable 
    """ 
    def get_query_set(self): 
        queryset = super(SpecialOrderingChangeList, self).get_query_set() 
        return queryset.order_by(*self.model._meta.ordering)
```

Add this method in your `admin.ModelAdmin`

```
def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs): 
    return SpecialOrderingChangeList
```

source: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/PvjClVVgD-s

Comment: Use 'get_queryset' instead of 'get_query_set' in django 1.11

Answer (score 3):

until django 1.4 (currently in alpha) the django admin only orders by the first column in `Meta ordering`. You can work around this by overriding the queryset:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.order_by('last_name', 'first_name')
        return qs
```

Comment: Thanks, however I tried your code but it didn't take effect, I'm using Django 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Further to user535010's response above:
I struggled because after adding the suggested code I was no longer able to order the fields by clicking on the headings in the admin list view.  I modified the get_changelist method suggested for MyModelAdmin as follows:

```
def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):  #ordering issue in 1.3 workaround
    try:
        if not request.GET['o']:
            return SpecialOrderingChangeList
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_changelist(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

Django model admin supports ordering by multiple values in Django 2.0+. You can now use it like this:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

The function required to make click-ordering work with the multi-column sort fix is this:

```
    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs): 
        try:
            if request.GET['o']:
                return super(ModelAdmin, self).get_changelist(request)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return SpecialOrderingChangeList
```

Other way round to jenniwren's answer :-)