# Django-admin display decorator sorting by multiple columns

Tags: django, django-admin

In my database model, I have last and first name. In the django-admin site, I want to display "Lastname, Firstname" and have this column sortable. For this, I'm using the `@admin.display` decorator in my `admin.ModelAdmin` class.

This decorator takes an `ordering` parameter which can be a string, referencing a model field name to sort by, for example:

```
    @admin.display(description = "Full name", ordering = "last_name")
    def full_name(self, obj):
        return f"{obj.last_name}, {obj.first_name}"
```

However, this will only sort by `last_name`, obviously, and therefore people with the same last name will end up in arbitrary order. I've tried:

```
@admin.display(description = "Full name", ordering = ["last_name", "first_name"])
```

Or using a list instead of a tuple, but this fails ("'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'").

I searched for this and found my exact question unanswered here: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/how-to-tell-admin-display-decorator-to-order-the-results-by-two-columns/21418 Also in this post: [Django-admin order by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855151/django-admin-order-by-multiple-fields) someone suggests that the intuitive list syntax would work with "ordering", but this does not seem to work inside the decorator.

Comment: Sadly enough no, perhaps `Concat('last_name', Value(','), 'first_name')` works?

Comment: That does indeed work, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that indeed does not work, I tried the same some time ago, and found out it was not implemented (that way). But for this specific case, you can just reproduce the behavior with [**`Concat`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#concat), to concatenate the two fields together and produce a string, so as in the body of the function:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat


@admin.display(
    description='Full name',
    ordering=Concat('last_name', Value(','), 'first_name'),
)
def full_name(self, obj):
    return f'{obj.last_name}, {obj.first_name}'
```